# node.js module ntwitter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, express, twitter-oauth

I have tried to use ntwitter node.js module.I have read all the instructions and type the sample code,but it is not working.The code is as follows:

```
var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  access_token_key: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
  access_token_secret: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
});
twit.stream('user', {track:'nodejs'},function(stream) {
      console.log('stream==========================',stream);
      stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('=============================================',data);
      });
});
```

The console.log for stream displays something like this:

```
stream========================== { buffer: '',
  destroy: [Function],
  _events: { _data: [Function: processTweet] } }
```

But console.log for data does not display anything.I am stuck and don't know what to do.Can anyone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your access_token_key and access_token_secret values are incorrect. These are supposed be generated keys, not URLs.

There should be a button on your Twitter Developer page to Create Your Access Token. Click it, and use the values provided there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into a similar issue. Make sure the time on your server is set correctly, otherwise oAuth will fail